# How do I return one-to-many records in a specific order with Dapper and multi-mapping?

Tags: dapper, multi-mapping

From [Github](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net):

> Dapper allows you to map a single row to multiple objects. This is a
>   key feature if you want to avoid extraneous querying and eager load
>   associations.
>
> Example:
>
> Consider 2 classes: Post and User

```
> class Post {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Title { get; set; }
>     public string Content { get; set; }
>     public User Owner { get; set; } }
> 
> class User {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; } }
```

> Now let us say that we want to map a query that joins both the posts
>   and the users table. Until now
>   if we needed to combine the result of 2 queries, we'd need a new
>   object to express it but it makes more sense in this case to put the
>   User object inside the Post object.

When I do this (My classes are different names, but same construct), I get a Post and a User, a Post and a User.  I'm using the Web API, so this is all JSON, if that matters.  This is the way I'd see it if I did straight SQL in the Management Studio, you get the many rows and the corresponding User records

What if I want to send back the JSON that has the User once and all the posts in an array, then the next User, array of posts, etc.

```
id   title    content   id    name
1    Article1 Content1  55  Smith
2    Article2 Content2  55  Smith
3    Article3 Content3  55  Smith
```

I get the JSON back that has the User information over and over (as expected but not wanted).  It's backwards.

What I want is a JSON object that has a format like this (I think this is correct):

```
{
  "User": 55,
  "Name": "Smith",
  "Post": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "title1",
      "content":"MyContent1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "title2",
      "content":"MyContent2"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "title3",
      "content":"MyContent2"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I do this?  Right now I get the reverse.  I thought I would simply change the classes around, but I did not because of the instructions on Github, the "makes more sense" part.  I am using this,

```
(List<Post>)db.Query<Post, User, Paper>(sqlString, (post, user) => { post.user = user; return post; }, splitOn: "id");
```

I know I don't need the splitOn here, but in my real query the name is different than id.

This is pretty close:

https://www.tritac.com/developers-blog/dapper-net-by-example/

```
public class Shop {
  public int? Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Url {get;set;}
  public IList<Account> Accounts {get;set;}
}

public class Account {
  public int? Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Address {get;set;}
  public string Country {get;set;}
  public int ShopId {get;set;}
}

var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Shop>()
conn.Query<Shop, Account, Shop>(@"
                    SELECT s.*, a.*
                    FROM Shop s
                    INNER JOIN Account a ON s.ShopId = a.ShopId                    
                    ", (s, a) => {
                         Shop shop;
                         if (!lookup.TryGetValue(s.Id, out shop)) {
                             lookup.Add(s.Id, shop = s);
                         }
                         if (shop.Accounts == null) 
                             shop.Accounts = new List<Account>();
                         shop.Accounts.Add(a);
                         return shop;
                     },
                     ).AsQueryable();

var resultList = lookup.Values;
```

It makes the first object identifier.  Not sure if I can use it like that or not.  But this does do the array of books like I was asking, and I did not have to create a special object.  Originally, it was supposed to be on Google Code, but I couldn't find this test on Github.

Answer (score 1):

Since your SQL query is returning the flat records, i suggest you create a flat POCO and use dapper to map the result set to a collection of this. Once you have data in this collection, you can use LINQ GroupBy method to group it the way you want.

Assuming you have classes like

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<Post> Posts { set;get;}
}
public class Post
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string Title{ set;get;}
  public string Content { set;get;}
}
```

Now create the POCO for the flat result set row

```
public class UserPost
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Title { set; get; }
    public string Content { set; get; }

    public int UserId { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

Now update your SQL query to return a result set with column name matching the above properties.

Now use Dapper to get the flat records

```
var userposts= new List<UserPost>();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
{
    userposts = conn.Query<UserPost>(query).ToList();
}
```

Now apply GroupBy

```
var groupedPosts = userposts.GroupBy(f => f.UserId, posts => posts, (k, v) =>
    new User()
    {
        UserId = k,
        Name = v.FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Posts = v.Select(f => new Post() { Id = f.Id, 
                                           Title= f.Title, 
                                           Content = f.Content})
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I thought multimapping was supposed to keep me from having create other objects.

Comment: Can you tell me which function signature your GroupBy uses?  I do not know what the first two lambdas are for.  What is the groupby doing?  What is f in this lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use .[QueryMultiple](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/Tests.QueryMultiple.cs)

```
    [Test]
    public void TestQueryMultiple()
    {
        const string sql = @"select UserId = 55, Name = 'John Doe'
                    select PostId = 1, Content = 'hello' 
                    union all select PostId = 2, Content = 'world'";

        var multi = _sqlConnection.QueryMultiple(sql);
        var user = multi.Read<User>().Single();
        user.Posts = multi.Read<Post>().ToList();

        Assert.That(user.Posts.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(user.Posts.First().Content, Is.EqualTo("hello"));
        Assert.That(user.Posts.Last().Content, Is.EqualTo("world"));
    }
```

**Update:**

To return multiple users and their posts:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestQueryMultiple2()
    {
        const string sql = @"select UserId = 55, Name = 'John Doe'
                    select UserId = 55, PostId = 1, Content = 'hello' 
                    union all select UserId = 55, PostId = 2, Content = 'world'";

        var multi = _sqlConnection.QueryMultiple(sql);
        var users = multi.Read<User>().ToList();
        var posts = multi.Read<Post>().ToList();

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            user.Posts.AddRange(posts.Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId));
        }

        Assert.That(users.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(users.First().Posts.First().Content, Is.EqualTo("hello"));
        Assert.That(users.First().Posts.Last().Content, Is.EqualTo("world"));
    }
```

Comment: What if I am returning a List<User>?  I can't return a Single() to List.